# VueJS v-for class alternation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i can't found other way to recreate something like the tripped for table in bootstrap ...

so this is the best way ? there is a native alternative for doing %2 ?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  props: {
    data:{
      type: Array,
      default: function(){ return ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; },
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.stripped {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-for='(datum, i) in data' :class='{stripped: i%2}' >{{ datum }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intent on doing this using Vue then that seems like a reasonably clean solution to me.

Alternatively you could look at using `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)` CSS selectors?